# Why is Dell D620 SMP battery not charging?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery, dell-latitude, charging

What problems may cause the battery not to charge or Ubuntu to report only a 6% charge?

The AC Adapter is warm, emitting a high-pitched buzzing noise, and says "INPUT: 100-240 V ~1.5A / 50/60HZ", "OUTPUT: 19.5V (solid overbar, dotted underbar) 4.62A".

I just bought a replacement battery from Yahoo Shopping Japan; came about 40% charged. Followed the instructions to discharge it down to 10%, wound up using it past then, tonight plugging it in to fully charge as directed, using the computer while charging it.

Lubuntu 16.04 reports the battery as 'Charging', but it has been at 6% for 30 minutes, so it appears not to be charging. Dual-booting into Windows 7, it says "7% available (plugged in, not charging)".

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems:
1. The power source does not hold the voltage under load. You have an original AC-adapter with a big DELL sticker (such as https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/BFcAAOSwkvFaWkfF/s-l1600.jpg) or Chinese with a different sticker (it is also significantly lighter in weight)? original AC-adapter should not produce a high-frequency sound, it is so filled inside with sealants and compounds that there is nothing to squeak there. The purchased battery consumes a larger charging current, which the power supply unit can not provide. Try replacing the power supply.

2. The purchased battery is not assembled from all quality batteries. It is enough 1-2 most cheap and bad elements that the battery does not accept a charge. Try to find a similar laptop and try to charge it in it.

Comment: It is Chinese with a different sticker saying "AC ADAPTER" and specifications; it is not the Dell sticker you show. I cannot say whether it is lighter than a Dell adapter, but it is relatively light. It does not feel filled with liquid ('sealants'?), and it is warm to the touch after the laptop has been on for several minutes with battery at "0% charging".

Comment: with a 75% chance the battery is to blame. to safely diagnose a battery failure, you need to insert it into another laptop. But, probably, you do not have such an opportunity. Without disassembling the battery, you can not determine what is defective.